# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have upgraded my Android studio to Flamingo. I am facing an issue related to realm plugin in project level gradle file.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Pulse_Patient'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/3.7.2/realm-gradle-plugin-3.7.2.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/3.7.2/realm-gradle-plugin-3.7.2.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2"
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()`your text`
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```